# Command line to change file names

Tags: rename, filenames

I have a large number of files which I would like to rename. Here is an example of how I would like to change the file names:

From:

```
PD5 grey nice display 1.jpg
```

To:

```
pd5-grey-nice-display-showcase-1.jpg
```

What is the command line code I would need to use?

Answer (score 6):

If you have Perl's `rename`:

```
rename -n '$_=lc;s/ /-/g;s/([0-9]+)\./showcase-$1\./' your_file_name
```

should do the trick.

**Explanation:**

- `$_=lc` convert all characters to lowercase
- `s/ /-/g` replace all single spaces by a dash (use `s/ +/-/g` if you anticipate multiple consecutive spaces)
- `s/([0-9]+)\./showcase-$1\./` looks for a sequence of consecutive digits followed by a dot (marking the filename extension) and adds `showcase-` before that sequence.

**Note**

- The above code **won't do anything**, it will just print out the new file name without actually renaming the file. After you make sure it works correctly, you can remove the `-n` switch.